# How do i stop glassfish from trying to connect to a database cluster node that is down, during deployment?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, glassfish

I'm working on a web application using spring, Glassfish, hibernate and MySQL. I have a MySQL cluster with 3 nodes. The application is aware of the location the user accesses it from, and dispatches the database queries to the appropriate nodes. I want to implement some database fault tolerance, meaning that when a node is down, the application will redirect the query to the nearest active node. Things are working well, but I encounter a problem when I try to deploy and one node is down. Glassfish tries to connect to the node that is down, and obviously, does not succeed. But it keeps on trying for some minutes. This is the exception I get in the logs:

```
[#|2012-05-18T21:26:21.557+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=102;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|18.05.2012 21:26:21 DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1831) - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor128.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor125.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
... 19 more
|#]
```

I've tried setting some hibernate properties related to connection testing, but to no effect. Is there a timeout property, or some boolean property that I could set, so that I could deploy faster? These are the datasource properties I'm currently using:

```
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are the datasource properties for Hibernate or for the Spring bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the property i was looking for through trial and error:

```
<property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="1"/>
```